# Facing issues with S3 operation using V4 authentication

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am working on a product (which supports V4 Auth) which works like Amazon S3 and the same Amazon S3 APIs can be used to perform S3 operations on my product too.

The problem I am facing with my Java code is I am able to create Bucket/PUT object in the bucket but not through V4 authentication, the requests are going via V2 Auth which I don't want. I am using the latest AWS-JAVA-SDKs for S3 operations but still the requests are going with V2 auth. I don't know what needs to be done in my code so that requests uses V4 Auth (and not V2 Auth).

My code -

```
package com.amplidata.awstest;
/*
 * Copyright 2010-2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights            Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is      distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND,   either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.Protocol;
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

 /**
 * This sample demonstrates how to make basic requests to Amazon S3     using the
 * AWS SDK for Java.
 * <p>
 * <b>Prerequisites:</b> You must have a valid Amazon Web Services developer
 * account, and be signed up to use Amazon S3. For more information on Amazon
 * S3, see http://aws.amazon.com/s3.
 * <p>
  * <b>Important:</b> Be sure to fill in your AWS access credentials in the
 * AwsCredentials.properties file before you try to run this sample.
 * http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
 */
 public class S3Sample {
     private AmazonS3Client s3client;
    @Test
     public void s3operation() throws IOException {
         /*
          * This credentials provider implementation loads your AWS     credentials
          * from a properties file at the root of your classpath.
          * 
          * Important: Be sure to fill in your AWS access credentials in the
         * AwsCredentials.properties file before you try to run this sample.
         * http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
         */

        // Cut Example Code BEGIN
          // AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new
         // ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
        // Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
         // s3.setRegion(usWest2);
        // Cut Example Code END

        // Eucalyptus Code Changes BEGIN

        // create a credential for client
        final String username = "iwglsxxxxxv7a9b8e8838ec";
        final String password =   "3eni46tq4kokcyxxxxxxxnf4stk7fqgxxxxxxxmkdus";
        //final String regionName = "us-east-1";
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new  BasicAWSCredentials(username,
        password);

        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        final String serviceurl = "http://192.168.44.2:8080/";
        s3.setEndpoint(serviceurl);     
        S3ClientOptions s3ClientOptions = new S3ClientOptions();
        s3ClientOptions.setPathStyleAccess(true);
        s3.setS3ClientOptions(s3ClientOptions);

        // Eucalyptus Code Changes END

        String bucketName = "my-first-s3-bucket-" + UUID.randomUUID();
        String key = "MyObjectKey";

    System.out.println("===========================================");
    System.out.println("Getting Started with Amazon S3");
    System.out.println("===========================================\n");


        /*
         * Create a new S3 bucket - Amazon S3 bucket names are globally
         * unique, so once a bucket name has been taken by any user, you
         * can't create another bucket with that same name.
         * 
         * You can optionally specify a location for your bucket if you want
         * to keep your data closer to your applications or users.
         */         
        System.out.println("Creating bucket " + bucketName + "\n");
        s3.createBucket(bucketName);

        /*
         * List the buckets in your account
         */
        System.out.println("Listing buckets");
        for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
            System.out.println(" - " + bucket.getName());
        }
        System.out.println();

       /*
         * Upload an object to your bucket - You can easily upload a file to
         * S3, or upload directly an InputStream if you know the length of
         * the data in the stream. You can also specify your own metadata
         * when uploading to S3, which allows you set a variety of options
         * like content-type and content-encoding, plus additional metadata
         * specific to your applications.
         */
        //System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENFORCE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
        //s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,key,
                createSampleFile())); 
}



private static File createSampleFile() throws IOException {
    File file = File.createTempFile("aws-java-sdk-", ".txt");
    file.deleteOnExit();

    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
    writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
    writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
    writer.write("!@#$%^&*()-=[]{};':',.<>/?\n");
    writer.write("01234567890112345678901234\n");
    writer.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
    writer.close();

    return file;
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't have `//System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENFORCE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");` commented out?

Comment: Ya, i figured that out. there was some problem with my code, once that was fixed, i uncommented the System.setProperty & it worked. Thanks for your time :-)